# Pass an argument into a function to extract from array

Tags: functions, array, oop

I feel like this should be possible.

I have a function within my class which pulls a single row from my custom table:

```
class Get_Data{

    public static function get_data_single_db()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $user_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_table';
        $results = $wpdb->get_results(
            "SELECT *
                FROM $user_table_name
                WHERE unique_id = '$unique_id';"
        );

        return $results;
    }
```

The $results array contains 7 keys.  At the moment, outside of the class I am using this to extract a single key value:

```
Get_Data::get_data_single_db()[0]->key;
```

This works, but out of curiosity, could something like this work better:

```
Get_Data::get_data_single_db($key)
```

and in the function:

```
public static function get_data_single_db($key)
.....
return $results->key
```

Comment: Why should this not be possible? You can pass an argument. Where is your problem?

Comment: I said "I feel like this should be possible".  Using my code above it is not working as I expected so I asked here where the tweak was needed.

Comment: If your result is always one row with 7 fields, you should use $wpdb->get_row. Then you can return from your result as you wish like $result->$key, where $key may be the field you're looking for (e.g. 'first_name').

Comment: Ahhhh, let me try that out, sounds very promising! thanks man!

Comment: I get "Symbol '$key' is declared but not used" in the function.

Comment: If you want to get only one field from your query, it makes more sense to select only one field. You should use the $key in the query instead of asterisk (*) and return the $result.

Comment: @moped works great, thanks!